# How to modify the headsepline (KOMA) regarding its position (centering/flushleft)

Tags: koma-script, geometry, scrlayer-scrpage

Consider this MWE

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}% sets page style scrheadings 
\newlength\ratio
\setlength{\ratio}{2cm}
\usepackage[  % page layout modifications
  paper=a4paper,  %  - use A4 paper size
  foot=1.5\ratio,
  bindingoffset=.5\ratio,  %  - binding correction
  inner=\ratio,  %  - total body: left margin (odd pages)
  top=1.5\ratio,  %  - total body: top margin
  outer=2\ratio,  %  - total body: right margin (odd pages)
  bottom=2.5\ratio,  %  - total body: bottom margin
  marginparwidth=2\ratio,  %  - width for side note
  marginparsep=.25\ratio,  %  - space between notes and body text (content)
  % showframe,
]{geometry}

\AddToLayerPageStyleOptions{scrheadings}{%
  oninit=\KOMAoptions{%
    headsepline=.5pt:\textwidth+2\ratio,
    footsepline=.5pt:\ratio%
  }
}
\KOMAoptions{%
  headwidth={\textwidth+\ratio},%
  footwidth={\textwidth+\ratio}%
}
\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text
\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

The result is

[image: status quo]

However I would like to have the headsepline *not* centered but evolving to the inner border, the footsepline should only come in from the outer border.
This figure is modified and shows the desired outcome:

[image: status desideratus]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all: I do not see any reason to activate options `footsepline` and `headsepline` only whenever page-style `scrheadings` is initialized.

To align the head separation line by the outer margin of the head, you can use option `olines`. But this is not enough to move the foot separation line into the margin. To do so you either have to extend the footer to the paper edge or alternatively you can move the layer of the separation line towards the outer margin:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}% sets page style scrheadings 
\newlength\ratio
\setlength{\ratio}{2cm}
\usepackage[  % page layout modifications
  paper=a4paper,  %  - use A4 paper size
  foot=1.5\ratio,
  bindingoffset=.5\ratio,  %  - binding correction
  inner=\ratio,  %  - total body: left margin (odd pages)
  top=1.5\ratio,  %  - total body: top margin
  outer=2\ratio,  %  - total body: right margin (odd pages)
  bottom=2.5\ratio,  %  - total body: bottom margin
  marginparwidth=2\ratio,  %  - width for side note
  marginparsep=.25\ratio,  %  - space between notes and body text (content)
  %showframe,
]{geometry}

\KOMAoptions{%
  headwidth={\textwidth+\ratio},%
  footwidth={\textwidth+\ratio},%
  headsepline=.5pt:\textwidth+2.5\ratio,% extended by bindigoffset
  footsepline=.5pt:2\ratio,% extended corresponding to your image
  olines,
}
\ModifyLayer[addhoffset=\ifodd\value{page}\else -\fi 1.5\ratio]{scrheadings.foot.above.line}
\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text
\begin{document}
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image: left and right page]

Comment: fantastic answer!